# Nginx or Django is removing privileges to uploaded files

Tags: python, django, nginx

Currently I've a web app in Django that uploads files to a server folder in media/contracts/2018/5/3/myfile.pdf

the issue is that when the file is bigger than 2MB the uploaded file permissions.

```
-rw------- 1 root root 4664244 May  3 18:21 31ee8079-6ca9-4979-a0c1-d276b588e361.pdf
```

if the file is lower than 2MB gets.

```
-rwxrwxr-x 1 root root 2687931 May  3 14:14 8e498e49-ced8-45d2-af49-4234293d937c.pdf
```

my Urls.py for media_root is:

```
url(r'^media/(?P<path>.*)$', serve, {'document_root': settings.MEDIA_ROOT}),
```

Answer (score 2):

you can read about how to set file upload permission in the [django docs](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/2.0/ref/settings/#std:setting-FILE_UPLOAD_PERMISSIONS)

in your settings.py you can set the permissions for uploaded files e.g. 
`FILE_UPLOAD_PERMISSIONS = 0644`

If you don't have a `FILE_UPLOAD_MAX_MEMORY_SIZE` set, files over 2.5MB will be directly streamed to the filesystem.  This is what is causing the difference in permission between the two files.